# node.js module installation release Microsoft.Cpp.x 64.Targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm getting the following error when installing:

```
npm install ecrud
```

I'm the only one on my team getting this problem.  Previously I got a separate error message stating that I needed .NET 2 SDK or to add the path to VCBuild.exe.  I installed the SDK, Visual Studio, and Visual C++ express.  Then I see this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(29
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(29
7,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.
7,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.
  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version nu
  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version nu
mber. [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ecrud\node_modules\mongodb\node_mod
ules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
mber. [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ecrud\node_modules\mongodb\node_mod
ules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x
64.Targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [C:\Pr
ogram Files\nodejs\node_modules\ecrud\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\bu
ild\bson.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x
64.Targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [C:\Pr
ogram Files\nodejs\node_modules\ecrud\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbero
s\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
npm http 408 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0
.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
```

Comment: Install the appropriate versions of softwares as mentioned [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to install Microsoft Visual Studio (specifying the version of VS): npm install ecrud --msvs_version=2012

Comment: You're a Saint! The argument "msvs_version=" works like a charm!

Comment: You may also need to change the Visual Studio install to include "Tools and Windows SDK".